# Find max and min value using group by on same table

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table.

```
name       gender   age
 NAME1  F   21
 NAME2  M   23
 NAME3  F   26
 NAME4  F   42
 NAME5  M   52
```

Now i want to display the min  aged person including with gender and max aged person including with gender.

That is

```
 NAME1 F 21 NAME5 M 52
```

I have used the following query.But it is not giving correct result for me.

```
select max(v1.age),v1.gender, min(v2.age),v2.gender from table_name v1
,table_name v2 where v1.id =v2.id;
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are missing the `group by`. Your SQL is essentially invalid but MySQL will return "indeterminate" (read: random) values. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: Please have a look here. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48203/how-to-get-max-and-min-in-group-by-query

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query for the maximum:

```
select name, gender, age 
from table_name 
where age = (select max(age) from table_name) 
limit 1
```

Returning both the maximum and minimum names etc. is doable but probably more complicated than running 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT NAME, gender, age 
FROM t1 
WHERE age = (SELECT MAX(age) FROM t1) 
UNION
SELECT NAME, gender, age 
FROM t1 
WHERE age = (SELECT MIN(age) FROM t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via a triple self join and a having clause:

```
SELECT 
    min(tmin.age) as min_age,
    t1.*,
    max(tmax.age) as max_age,
    t2.*
from myTable t1
join myTable tmin
join myTable t2
join myTable tmax
group by t1.id, t2.id
having min_age = t1.age and max_age = t2.age
```

It feels quite hacky, though it is the only way you will get it without subqueries. And yes, max and min age will appear twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

`select v1.age, v1.gender, v2.age, v2.gender from table_name v1, table_name v2 where v1.age =(select max(age) from table_name) and v2.age=(select min(age) from table_name)`